# Question about Duncan Laurence - Arcade

Tags: voice, sheet-music

I'm trying to sing this song.

Maybe someone can explain to me. If you look at music sheet for this song(https://musescore.com/user/31196819/scores/5480313) you see that after "I carried it, carried it, carried home" it goes from fourth to fifth octave.

Can anybody confirm is that how he sings it here:

Because I don't hear a change in octave at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the sheet music is accurate. Bars 7-8 and 19-20 contain different lyrics but the same melody an octave apart. Actually the entire 12 bars is almost exactly the same an octave apart but I’m using those two bars as an example since they start the two sections. At bars 7-8 (0:14) he is singing in a deep husky voice. At bars 19-20 (0:35) he is clearly singing an octave higher. Use the time marks I indicated to listen to the two phrases  back to back.

Something to keep in mind is the vocal line is transposed. It sounds an octave below written which is very common for male vocals. This is usually indicated by a small “8” under the treble clef but many times it is not used.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on vocal line being transposed. What does it mean, and does it change how it should be sang?

Comment: @Piliponful Male vocal parts are usually transposed by an octave, which means it sounds one octave below where it is written. The reason for this is for convenience. Otherwise many notes would be written with multiple ledger lines below the staff. If you play the same music on a piano which is non-transposing the piano will sound one octave higher than the vocal.

Comment: ok, I think I'm starting to understand what you're saying.

But I really want to understand what does it mean for me in terms of singing this song.

Does it mean that because it's transposed I should sing everything an octave lower?

So in case of this song I should sing "Broken hart is all that's left" not in forth octave, but in third. And "I'm afraid of all I am" not in fifth, but in forth?

That's what I understood from you explanation, is it correct?

And in advance, thank you so much, you're opening my eyes here it seems.

Comment: @Piliponful Yes, that’s right. The first note of the phrase that starts with “broken” is written as C4, middle C, but is sung as a C3, one octave below. The first note of “I’m afraid” is written as C5 but is sung as C4, which is actually middle C. This is how it is sung by Duncan Laurence.

Comment: Men, I'm so grateful for this clarification, thank you so much.

Comment: Is there a way to tell from music sheet if it's transposed?

Comment: @Piliponful Most of the time male vocals are transposed because their highest notes are within the staff (unless you’re Philip Bailey or Robert Plant!) A sure fire way is to compare it to the same notes on the piano and see if it sounds like unison or octaves. It’s usually easy to tell.